# Catch error in a for loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, avro

I have a for loop on an avro data reader object

```
for i in reader:
    print i
```

then I got a unicode decode error in the for statement so I wanted to ignore that particular record. So I did this

```
try:
    for i in reader:
        print i
except:
    pass
```

but it does not continue further. How can I overcome this problem

Edit: Error trace added

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modify.py", line 22, in <module>
    for record in reader:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/datafile.py", line 362, in next
    datum = self.datum_reader.read(self.datum_decoder) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 445, in read
    return self.read_data(self.writers_schema, self.readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 490, in read_data
    return self.read_record(writers_schema, readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 690, in read_record
    field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 468, in read_data
    return decoder.read_utf8()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 233, in read_utf8
    return unicode(self.read_bytes(), "utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

could it be due to the fact that the file was corrupted?

Edit2: 
As per suggestion in answers to go through iterobject I modified code and got this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modify.py", line 28, in <module>
    print next(iterobject)["filepath"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/datafile.py", line 362, in next
    datum = self.datum_reader.read(self.datum_decoder) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 445, in read
    return self.read_data(self.writers_schema, self.readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 490, in read_data
    return self.read_record(writers_schema, readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 690, in read_record
    field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 468, in read_data
    return decoder.read_utf8()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 233, in read_utf8
    return unicode(self.read_bytes(), "utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 226, in read_bytes
    return self.read(self.read_long())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.7-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 184, in read_long
    b = ord(self.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Comment: Can you also include the traceback of the exception. And also please fix the indentation of your code snippet.

Comment: Can you please post the value that you are having in reader .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your error is in `for i in`. Then try this, it will skip element in iterator if `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs.

```
iterobject = iter(reader)
while iterobject:
    try:
        print(next(iterobject))
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the try/except inside the loop:

```
    for i in reader:
       try: 
           print i
       except UnicodeEncodeError:
           pass
```

By the way it's good practice to specify the specific type of error you're trying to catch (like I did with `except UnicodeEncodeError:`, since otherwise you risk making your code very hard to debug!

Comment: @iLoveCamelCase In that case, there's a bug in the avro reader, and unless you want to hack that (fix the bug), there's little you can do in your script.

Comment: I was thinking if the avro file was corrupted

Answer (score 1):

You can except the [specific error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError), and avoid unknown errors to pass unnoticed.

Python 3.x:

```
try:
    for i in reader:
        print i
except UnicodeDecodeError as ue:
    print(str(ue))
```

Python 2.x:

```
try:
    for i in reader:
        print i
except UnicodeDecodeError, ue:
    print(str(ue))
```

By printing the error it's possible to know what happened. When you use only except, you except **anything** (And that can include an obscure RuntimeError), and you'll never know what happened. It can be useful sometimes, but it's dangerous and generally a bad practice.