# How to skip error and continue to run for loop and continue to the next line

Tags: python

```
counti=0

def removepunc(firstlist):
    global counti
    try:
        for words in firstlist:
            cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)
            counti += 1
            print(counti,":", cleanstr)
            Appended_Data.to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False)
        return(counti,":", cleanstr)
    except:
        pass
```

I am trying to do here is to create a function to read a column from an excel sheet and remove special characters and punctuation, after that save it into a new excel sheet.

The column consists of a string that has multiple sentences and special characters. I manage to remove those special characters and punctuation, however, there is a single line in the column that is completely empty.

When the code reaches that line(line 506) it gives out an error that there needs to be a string or byte inside. I used try and except so the error does not show up but the code just ends there. How do I make it skip (line 507) that line and continue(line 508) running the function?

Comment: put a try except block around `cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)` and in the except block, put `continue`

Comment: Where is line 506?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch error in a for loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521760/catch-error-in-a-for-loop-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `try` and `except` is in the wrong place.

When you get an error in the `try` block

```
    for words in firstlist:
        cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)
        counti += 1
        print(counti,":", cleanstr)
        Appended_Data.to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False
```

The execution of this *whole block* is stopped and the `except` block is called.

```
    except:
        pass
```

This is at the end of the function so the function ends and returns `None`

To fix that put the `try` block around `cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)` and instead of `pass`ing use `continue` so the control goes back to the next word in the loop.

```
def removepunc(firstlist):
    global counti
    for words in firstlist:
        try:
            cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)
        except:
            # Not sure if you want to increase counti here
            # if so add the line here
            continue 
        counti += 1
        print(counti,":", cleanstr)
        Appended_Data.to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False)
    return(counti,":", cleanstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
   
    def removepunc(firstlist):
        global counti
        for words in firstlist:
            try:
               cleanstr = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', words)
            except:
               continue
            counti += 1
            print(counti,":", cleanstr)
            Appended_Data.to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False)
        return(counti,":", cleanstr)
```